# What is the Class Of List<Foo> in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, interface

```
Class c = List<Foo>.class
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you elaborate the context for which you thought to need this construct to solve your problem, then we may be able to provide suggestions how to solve it.

Comment: I think the solution would be to just write "Class c = List.class"

Comment: (It's using Mockito, if you're interested)

Comment: ripper234: `Class<List> c = List.class;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't one. In Java, concrete generic types have no exact runtime type representation. This is a consequence of the much-maligned *type erasure*. Effectively, this means that `List<Foo>` is the same runtime type as `List<Bar>`; checking whether generic operations are legal happens at compile time, not runtime. Once you're in bytecode, they're all `List`, so saying something like `List<X>.class` is nonsensical to some degree.

See [**this FAQ**](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ106) for more details.